# How can I adjust the code so that the tabs reset

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I use the code below as an abview in Sharepoint 2013, now my question is how I adjust this so that when you switch tabs the other tab remains, by this I mean if I go into a folder in Tab 1 and then in another tab that Tab 1 goes back to its original field and does not stay in the folder that was last viewed, now we have to keep pressing F5.

```
(function() {

var AP = "",
    sec = 0,
    Header = "none",
    Split = "No",
    Expand = "",
    Print = "";

if (document.forms[0].elements["_wikiPageMode.value"] == "true" || document.forms[0].elements["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"].value == "1") {
    return;
}

var el = document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"),
    p = el[el.length - 1],
    sT, a, sep, tabRow;

do {
    p = p.parentNode;
    sT = p.innerHTML.split("MSOZoneCell_WebPart");
} while (sT.length < 4 && p.parentNode.id != "MSO_ContentTable")

if (p.getAttribute("contenteditable") == "true") {
    return;
}

if (p.nodeName == "DIV") {
    sep = document.createElement("div");
    p.insertBefore(sep, p.firstChild);
    tabRow = document.createElement("div");
    p.insertBefore(tabRow, p.firstChild);
} else {
    sep = document.createElement("td");
    var sepTR = document.createElement("tr");
    sepTR.appendChild(sep);
    tabRow = document.createElement("td");
    var tabTR = document.createElement("tr");
    tabTR.appendChild(tabRow);
    if (p.nodeName == "TBODY") {
        p.insertBefore(sepTR, p.firstChild);
        p.insertBefore(tabTR, p.firstChild);
    } else if (p.nodeName == "TR") {
        p.parentNode.insertBefore(tabTR, p);
        p.parentNode.insertBefore(sepTR, p);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

sep.className = "et-separator";
tabRow.className = "et-tabrow";
var children = p.childNodes;
p = p.parentNode;
var etRoot = [],
    etHeader = [],
    etTab = [],
    tabsID = [];

for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
    try {
        var d = children[j].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i].id.indexOf("WebPartTitle") == 0) {
                var WPid = d[i].id.replace(/WebPartTitle/, "");
                if (d[i].innerHTML.indexOf("(Hidden)") == -1) {
                    var up = d[i];
                    while (up != children[j]) {
                        if (up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id=WebPart' + WPid + ' ') >= 0 || up.parentNode.innerHTML.indexOf('id="WebPart' + WPid + '" ') >= 0) {
                            WPid = "et" + WPid;
                            etHeader[WPid] = up;
                            etRoot[WPid] = children[j];
                            etTab[WPid] = d[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].cloneNode(true);
                            etTab[WPid].id = WPid;
                            etTab[WPid].className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
                            etTab[WPid].onclick = function() {
                                activateTab(this);
                            };
                            tabRow.appendChild(etTab[WPid]);
                            tabsID.push(WPid);
                            break;
                        }
                        up = up.parentNode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {}
}

var Tabs = tabRow.getElementsByTagName("span"),
    TabCount = Tabs.length;

if (Split == "Yes") {
    var sd = document.createElement("div"),
        index = Math.floor(TabCount * 0.5);
    tabRow.insertBefore(sd, Tabs[index]);
}

if (AP.length && sec > 0) {
    sec = sec * 1000;
    interval = "";
    a = document.createElement("span");
    a.innerHTML = "|>";
    a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick = function() {
        if (interval == "") {
            this.innerHTML = "||";
            interval = window.setInterval(function() {
                Autoplay();
            }, sec)
        } else {
            this.innerHTML = "|>";
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            interval = ""
        }
    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
    var Autoplay = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < TabCount; i++)
            if (Tabs[i].className == "et-tab et-activetab") {
                var j = (i + 1) % TabCount;
                activateTab(Tabs[j]);
                break
            }
    };
    if (AP == "Play") {
        a.innerHTML = "||";
        interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            Autoplay();
        }, sec)
    };
}

if (Expand.length) {
    a = document.createElement("span");
    a.innerHTML = Expand;
    a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < tabsID.length; i++) {
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className = etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/et-offscreen/g, "");
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].style.pageBreakAfter = "always";
            etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display = "";
        }
    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
}

if (Print.length) {
    a = document.createElement("span");
    a.innerHTML = Print;
    a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
    a.onclick = function() {
        this.style.display = "none";
        var f = document.getElementById("s4-workspace") || document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
            ed = p.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement(p.nodeName), p);
        f.appendChild(p);
        for (j = 0; j < f.childNodes.length - 1; j++) {
            try {
                f.childNodes[j].className += " et-offscreen";
            } catch (e) {}
        }
        a = document.createElement("span");
        a.innerHTML = "Back to Page";
        a.className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
        a.onclick = function() {
            this.previousSibling.style.display = "inline-block";
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
            ed.parentNode.insertBefore(p, ed);
            ed.parentNode.removeChild(ed);
            for (j = 0; j < f.childNodes.length; j++) {
                try {
                    f.childNodes[j].className = f.childNodes[j].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g, "");
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        };
        tabRow.appendChild(a);
    };
    tabRow.appendChild(a);
}

function activateTab(t) {
    document.cookie = tabsID.join("_") + "=" + t.id + ";path=/";
    for (i = 0; i < tabsID.length; i++) {
        etHeader[tabsID[i]].style.display = Header;
        if (t.id == tabsID[i]) {
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className = "et-tab et-activetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className = etRoot[tabsID[i]].className.replace(/\s*et-offscreen/g, "");
        } else {
            etTab[tabsID[i]].className = "et-tab et-inactivetab";
            etRoot[tabsID[i]].className += " et-offscreen";
        }
    }
}
var m = GetCookie(tabsID.join("_")) ? GetCookie(tabsID.join("_")) : tabsID[0];
activateTab(etTab[m]);
})();
```

I tried to add/change the code but my knowledge is not good enough